# Best practices for async await when retrieving data from firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I had this error before

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
> This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
> To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect
> cleanup function.

This is my `useEffect` where I retrieve data from firestore and it does remove the error:

```
 useEffect(async () => {
    let isMounted = true;
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "product"));
    const arr = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      arr.push({
        ...doc.data(),
        id: doc.id,
      });
      if (isMounted) setProduct(arr);
    });
    return () => {
      isMounted = false;
    };
  }, []);
```

Is the `useEffect` alright or will this cause any problems in the future? And am I mounting this right?

Comment: ‘setProduct’ is a setState, right? If yes, your implementation looks good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your current code, you call `useEffect` with an `async` function that uses `await`. Because you are using an `async` function, the unsubscriber function you are returning to `useEffect` is wrapped in a `Promise` instead of being the raw callback itself. This means that the `useEffect` never sees that the return value is a callback function in time for it to be useful.

The solution to this is to make sure the function passed into the `useEffect` is not `async`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  let isMounted = true;

  const doFetch = async () => {
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "product"));
    const arr = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      arr.push({
        ...doc.data(),
        id: doc.id,
      });
      if (isMounted) setProduct(arr);
    });
  };

  doFetch() // start the async work
    .catch((err) => {
      if (!isMounted) return; // unmounted, ignore.
      // TODO: Handle errors in your component
      console.error("failed to fetch data", err);
    });

  return () => {
    isMounted = false;
  };
}, []);
```

There are `useAsyncEffect` implementations that allow you to skip the `setState()` and `useEffect()` boilerplate that you are currently using. I have detailed these in similar answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70183791/3068190) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69140217/3068190).

Comment: Thank you, can I also add a loading with this `if (isMounted) setProduct(arr);
      setLoading(true);` or should I wrap both the `product` and `setLoading` with the `if`?

Comment: @PennieCorhon Yes, you will also need to protect `setLoading` by the same `if` statement. However, I would instead recommend inverting the condition like I did with the `catch` handler by using `if (!isMounted) return; // unmounted, ignore.` and then continue on with your state changes below it (`setProduct`, `setLoading`, etc.) This is known as "failing fast".

Answer (score 2):

Ths look okay. But it's best to extract the fetching logic into a separate function instead of having the entire logic in the body of the `useEffect`. It gets easy to re-use the logic for functionality like retrying if the request failed on mount.

I would do something like this...

- Note: I removed the `isMounted` as the effect with be run when the component is mounted.
- Wrap the function in an async function(named or anonymous) inside the useEffect and run it immediately.

```
// Re-usable logic for stuff like reload/retry
const fetchProduct = async () => {
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "product"));
  const arr = [];
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    arr.push({
      ...doc.data(),
      id: doc.id,
    });
  });
  setProduct(arr); // Moved this out of the loop to be run once.
}

useEffect(async () => {
  (async () => {
    await fetchProduct();
    // await other async operations here.
  })(); // This immediately runs the func async.
}, []);
```